# Subversion - Make a branch and add all the following revisions to it

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a project in subversion.  I would like to make a branch at revision 16000 and include all the revisions up to 16011 in it.  I then would like to remove 16001 to 16011 from the trunk since I just want those revisions to be in the branch.
Is there a way to do this?

BTW I am using toirtoise svn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to make a branch at revision 16000 and include all the
>   revisions up to 16011 in it.

To simplify it -  create branch from version 16011.

Right click `TortoiseSVN > Branch... > Speciffic revision in repository` and specify 16011.

> I then would like to remove 16001 to 16011 from the trunk since I just
>   want those revisions to be in the branch.

Use [reverse merge](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html) to achieve this:

Right click `TortoiseSVN > Merge... > Merge a range of revisions... > Reverse merge`. Click `Show log` and choose range from 16001 - 160011.

Do not forget to `commit`.

[Note](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html):

> Since TortoiseSVN never loses data, your “rolled back” revisions still
>   exist as intermediate revisions in the repository. Only the HEAD
>   revision was changed to a previous state. If you want to make
>   revisions **disappear completely** from your repository, erasing all trace
>   that they ever existed, you have to use more extreme measures. Unless
>   there is a really good reason to do this, it is not recommended. One
>   possible reason would be that someone committed a confidential
>   document to a public repository.
>
> The only way to remove data from the repository is to use the
>   Subversion command line tool svnadmin. You can find a description of
>   how this works in the Repository Maintenance .

Comment: Brillant!  Thanks Ivan!